# Holomorphic funtion with $f(n) = n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions

I really struggle with this seemingly harmless question:

> Let $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be holomorphic with $f(n) = n$ for all $ n \in  \mathbb N$. Does this imply $f(z) = z$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$?

I don't really know what's the right way to solve this.
Obviously we can't use the Identity theorem, since $n \to \infty $. I doubt that I explicitly have to construct a function rather than giving an easy counter example. Any hints?

Comment: $f(z)=ze^{2\pi i z}$ ... and all example are multiples of this one.

Comment: An interesting question would be to classify all such functions.

Comment: Thanks. More obvious than I thought :)

Comment: @lisyarus That's a pretty easy exercise.

Comment: @Hellen Is it? Obviously, we can decompose $f(z) = z g(z) + h(z)$, where $g\big|_\mathbb{N}\equiv 1$ and $h\big|_\mathbb{N}\equiv 0$, but then I get stuck classifying $g$ and $h$.

Comment: @lisyarus Post it as a separate question. Someone, maybe me, will give you the construction in a second.

Comment: @lisyarus If you do, you can also ping me here so I don't miss it.

Comment: @Hellen Asked this as a separate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372771/describing-all-holomorphic-functions-such-that-fn-n-for-n-in-mathbbn

Answer (score 3):

Can you think of a nonzero function that vanishes at the integers?

Hint: think trig.

Comment: A second faster :D

Comment: $ n(sin(\pi n) + 1)$?

Comment: Yep. Or just $z+\sin{\pi z}$.